# how i update the order status in controller in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, order-status, magento-2.1.3, json

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;class Index extends Action
{
/**
    * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory
    */
   protected $resultJsonFactory;    public function __construct(
       Context $context,
       \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
   ) {
       parent::__construct($context);
       $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
   }    /**
    * Dispatch request
    *
    * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface|ResponseInterface
    * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException
    */
   public function execute()
   {
                        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
                        // $gff = $data['events'];
                         // print_r($gff);
                         $orderId = $data['id'];
                         $events = $data['events'];
                         $array = array();
                         foreach($events as $key => $value){
                         //print_r($value['id']);
                             $array[$key] = $value['code'];                             
                        //      if($value['code'] == "246")
                        // {
                        //     // print_r($value);
                        //         $orderId = $orderId;
                        //         $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                        //         $order = $objectManager->create('Magento/Sales/Model/Order')
                        //                    ->load('1372072');
                        //         $order->setState("pending")->setStatus("pending");
                        //         $order->save();
                        // }
                         }
                         print_r($array);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want to update order then you should load

***Order factory class/Repository***  class at *Your controller* and then using this class , can change order status;

Here i am going to use Repository `Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository`
So,you **should** inject this class on `__construct()`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
class Index extends Action
{
/**
    * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory
    */
   protected $resultJsonFactory;  
   protected $_orderRepository ;
   public function __construct(
       Context $context,
       Magento\Sales\Model $orderRepository,
       \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
   ) {
       parent::__construct($context);
       $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
       $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
   }    /**
    * Dispatch request
    *
    * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface|ResponseInterface
    * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException
    */
   public function execute()
   {
       $_order = $this->_orderRepository->getById($orderId); // it order is not order increment id
       $_order->setStatus('pending')->setState('pending');
       $_order->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply i ma getting error this when run the controller  Exception #0 (RuntimeException): Class Magento\Sales\Model does not exist

Comment: @RahulKatoch I'm also facing the same issue did you get the solution?